# Serilog configuration for elastic search with custom fields

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, .net-core, serilog, aspnetboilerplate

I am configuring ABP framework and want to use *Serilog* for logging. I have the following configuration in **Startup.cs**.

```
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.Elasticsearch(new ElasticsearchSinkOptions(new Uri("https://xxxxxxxxxx.com"))
    {
        AutoRegisterTemplate = true,
        TemplateName = "app-log",
        IndexFormat = "app-log-{0:yyyy.MM.dd}",
        CustomFormatter = new ElasticsearchJsonFormatter()
    })
    .WriteTo.File("Serilogs.txt")
    .MinimumLevel.Information()
    .CreateLogger();
Log.Logger = logger;
option.AddSerilog(logger);
```

With this configuration I am getting the log in following format:

```
{
    "_index": "app-log-2017.12.18",
    "_type": "logevent",
    "_id": "******",
    "_version": 1,
    "_score": null,
    "_source": {
        "@timestamp": "2017-12-18T15:34:54.3417552+05:30",
        "level": "Information",
        "messageTemplate": "{HostingRequestStartingLog:l}",
        "fields": {
            "Protocol": "HTTP/1.1",
            "Method": "GET",
            "ContentType": null,
            "ContentLength": null,
            "Scheme": "http",
            "Host": "localhost:21021",
            "PathBase": "",
            "Path": "/swagger/",
            "QueryString": "",
            "HostingRequestStartingLog": "Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:21021/swagger/  ",
            "EventId": {
                "Id": 1
            },
            "SourceContext": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost",
            "RequestId": "****:****",
            "RequestPath": "/swhaggfgggdefrf/"
        },
        "renderings": {
            "HostingRequestStartingLog": [
                {
                    "Format": "l",
                    "Rendering": "Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:21021/swagger/  "
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "fields": {
        "@timestamp": [
            1513591494341
        ]
    },
    "sort": [
        1513591494341
    ]
}
```

Currently, I am getting the *@timestamp*, *level* and the *message*.
By using `Log.Logger.Information("Some Template")`, we can get some information in the form of fields.

Now, in the ABP framework, there is a log for each event. Can anyone suggest a way of modifying those messages?
For example, for each request it shows *Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:*********** and for each response, it shows *Request finished in 7.8262ms 301*. Is it possible to modify these message? If yes then how?

I might not be clear for someone. Please comment if need any further clarifications. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Modify to what?

Comment: For example, I want to fix the fields in MessageTemplate and want to allow them to be null if that data is not available for any log. Like:
"fields": {
      "ElapsedMilliseconds": 144.6361,
      "StatusCode": 200,
      "ContentType": "application/javascript",
      "HostingRequestFinishedLog": "Request finished in 144.6361ms 200 application/javascript",
      "EventId": {
        "Id": 2
      },
      "SourceContext": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost",
      "RequestId": "0HLAHOT40NGN8:00000006",
      "RequestPath": "/swagger/ui/abc.js"
    },

Comment: I don't see what's null.

Comment: I mean, I want to fix ElapsedMilliseconds, StatusCode, ContentType, and RequestPath to be fixed properties for each log in the system. And any message should come in a field eg. EventLog. Let it be a starting log or finishing log or any other log. According to @Alper's answer, this has been defined by Asp.Net Core which is correct. However, is it possible to override that?

Comment: What do you mean by "want to fix ... to be fixed properties for each log in the system"?

Comment: Yes, even if that property is null/None.

Comment: *Je ne comprends pas*. Please edit your question to provide current and expected behavior.

Answer (score 3):

You cannnot modify those messages. 
Because Asp.Net Core framework writes those logs.
You can see the relevant line of the code

[image]

https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/d5ec0859e5496f83ca32bf8bfb68ce3c3efe832f/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/Internal/HostingRequestFinishedLog.cs#L53